# Custom function not running in an "if" statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in Javascript/jQuery as well as in Stack Overflow so please don't be mad at me if I made some huge mistakes.
I'm working on an HTML page using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and I have a pagination button group that switches the visibility of some  elements via adding or removing the "hide" class. I made some custom functions to do that in js, the matter is that those functions work fine when they are called by a button click, but they're not when I try to put them inside an "if" statement. I've already tried to put a simple 'alert' inside the statement to see if it's working and it does, but the functions are not running.

Can somebody explain to me what I'm missing?
Here's my code below:

HTML

```
<!--pagination-->
  <div id="pag-gal">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="btngrp">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="pi">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default attivo" id="p1">1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="p2">2</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="p3">3</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="pa">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--switching divs-->
  <div id="sob1" class="sob"></div>
  <div id="sob2" class="sob hide"></div>
  <div id="sob3" class="sob hide"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript/jQuery

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    function pag1(){
      return function(){
        $('#p1').addClass('attivo');
        $('#p2').removeClass('attivo');
        $('#p3').removeClass('attivo');
        $('#sob1').removeClass('hide');
        $('#sob2').addClass('hide');
        $('#sob3').addClass('hide');
      };
    };
    function pag2(){
      return function(){
        $('#p2').addClass('attivo');
        $('#p1').removeClass('attivo');
        $('#p3').removeClass('attivo');
        $('#sob2').removeClass('hide');
        $('#sob1').addClass('hide');
        $('#sob3').addClass('hide');
      };
    };
    function pag3(){
      return function(){
        $('#p3').addClass('attivo');
        $('#p1').removeClass('attivo');
        $('#p2').removeClass('attivo');
        $('#sob3').removeClass('hide');
        $('#sob2').addClass('hide');
        $('#sob1').addClass('hide');
      };
    };
    $('#p1').click(pag1());
    $('#p2').click(pag2());
    $('#p3').click(pag3());
    $('#pi').click(function(){
        if($('.attivo').is('#p1')){
          alert("The statement is true");  //This is working
          pag3();                          //this is not
        };
        if($('.attivo').is('#p2')){
          pag1();                          //nor this
        };
        if($('.attivo').is('#p3')){
          pag2();                          //or this
        };
      });
      $('#pa').click(function(){
          if($('.attivo').is('#p1')){
            pag2();
          };
          if($('.attivo').is('#p2')){
            pag3();
          };
          if($('.attivo').is('#p3')){
            pag1();
          };
        });
    });
  </script>
```

When I click a #p* button the pag* functions are working when I click #pi or #pa they are not.

Comment: Why are `pag1` etc are returning functions? Remove the `return function(){}` wrapper from them OR call `pag1()()`

Comment: if I remove the return(){} the function doesn't work, don't ask me why. Actually using pag*()() is working (even if it's not behaving like I would)

Answer (score 0):

Your pag* function **return** an anonimous function, so you have to assign to a variable first, then execute that:

```
function pag1(){
   return function(){
       //code
   };
};

var fun = pag1();
fun();
```

So you if statement became:

```
$('#pi').click(function(){
        if($('.attivo').is('#p1')){
          alert("The statement is true");  //This is working
          var p3 = pag3();                          //this is not
          p3();
        };
        //etc
      });
```

maybe rewrite all pag* function to execute directly:

```
function pag1(){
   $('#p1').addClass('attivo');
   $('#p2').removeClass('attivo');
   $('#p3').removeClass('attivo');
   $('#sob1').removeClass('hide');
   $('#sob2').addClass('hide');
   $('#sob3').addClass('hide');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you are returning function inside function so try calling page3()(); ie var i=page3();i();

you are operating on dom so don't need to return function . write logic only,dont return any function value

Comment: when I remove the "return" inside the function declaration they stop running. Anyway I can't understand why they are still working if I click  #p1 or #p2 or #p3